# I'm having trouble with formatting when using tooltips (or labels?) in D3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I’m totally noob-tastic (i.e. I have very little programming background and am trying to hack together a dashboard using borrowed code) but I am eager to learn more!

I’m currently hung up with what I hope is a small issue. 
I’m using a version of Bostock’s calendar example...

[calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miGfq.png)

...and have managed to get close to my desired outcome but I’m having trouble with the tooltip(?), specifically the second .attr under rect.filter below.

```
    d3.csv("BugeseraData.csv", function(error, csv) {

  csv.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Daily_total = parseInt(d.Daily_total);
  });

 var Daily_total_Max = d3.max(csv, function(d) { return d.Daily_total; });

  var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Date1; })
    .rollup(function(d) { return  Math.sqrt(d[0].Daily_total / Daily_total_Max); })
    .map(csv);


  rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(data[d]); })
      .attr("data-title", function(d) { return 'RwF ' +d  });
    $("rect").tooltip({container: 'body', html: true, placement:'top'}); 
});
```

The data has been imported from a .csv and has two “columns” (I'm using excel), titled 'Date1' and 'Daily_total' respectively.

When you mouse over a particular day I want to to return “RwF” + the value from the second column (the amount or Daily_total).

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO0Eh.png)

Currently, the “RwF” shows up but when I use d.Daily_total (the second column) the result is returning as “RwF undefined”. If I use “RwF” + d then I get “RwF” with the date (the value from the first column).

Would someone please help me understand the correct way to achieve this?

This is data from local government revenue collection and I want to be able to show collection amounts by day at a  glance. I want the actual collection amounts (not the date) to show upon mouseover.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The variable "data" contains your csv data in the form of JSON data. Take a look here how it works.

http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159

Try

```
'RwF ' + data[d]
```

instead of

```
'RwF ' + d
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel like that is helping to get closer... but I'm not getting the straight value from the .csv file (ie. 504,000), I'm getting a processed value (ie. 0.4191477477901931). I assume this is somehow coming from within the domain range (0, 1) set earlier.

Comment: I need to spend some time going through the link you sent. THANK YOU!